# Error "Invalid column name" in CTE

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having an issue using a column alias for a join in a cte. `Invalid column name` on the line with `RowNumber2 >= (t1.RowNumber - 20)` Anyone have a suggestion? Thanks..

```
DECLARE @latestDate Date = dbo.LatestDateWithPricingVolCountOver4k()

;WITH AllSymbsAndDates AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Symbol ORDER BY TradingDate) AS RowNumber, 
        Symbol, TradingDate
    FROM tblSymbolsMain 
    CROSS JOIN tblTradingDays
    WHERE TradingDate <= @latestDate
),
SymbsDatesGrouped AS
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            t1.Symbol, t1.TradingDate, t2.TradingDate AS TradingDate2, t1.RowNumber, 
            t2.RowNumber AS RowNumber2
        FROM AllSymbsAndDates t1 
        JOIN AllSymbsAndDates t2 ON t1.Symbol = t2.Symbol 
            AND RowNumber2 >= (t1.RowNumber - 20)
    ) t
)
SELECT 
    Symbol, TradingDate, TradingDate2, RowNumber, RowNumber2
FROM 
    SymbsDatesGrouped
ORDER BY 
     Symbol, TradingDate, TradingDate2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference a column alias in the `WHERE` or `JOIN` clauses - actually the only clause where you can reference an alias from the SELECT list is either in the `ORDER BY` (or in an outer scope, e.g. selecting from a subquery or CTE).

In this case, the solution is pretty trivial. Why not just say:

```
 AND t2.RowNumber >= (t1.RowNumber - 20)
```

?

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression referring to the column by 2 different names in the same query wouldn't work. I'm good to go.